# How can I figure out why my electric bill is so high?

Tags: electrical, wiring, meter

I have two homes (read flat or apartment) in two different buildings a few blocks apart. The homes are both the same size but, home 1 gets a huge electricity bill while home 2 gets 1/5 the electricity bill.

I've spoken to a few electricians and they have told me that this could be because of a few reasons;

1. Home One has a wiring issue where one of my neighbors homes is linked to mine. Have switched off all my appliances and the meter slows down to a near stop - I'm not quite sure if its supposed to stop completely or spin slowly when everything is off? Even if the ring is spinning when everything is off I assume, its slow spinning is adding a few units to my bill at the end of the month?
2. There is an earthing issue. I've apparently got some circuit installed that
3. The meter is busted (refer point number 1).

Any other guesses?

Comment: You've "apparently got some circuit installed that" ...? Also, some other things to try here: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1713/how-best-can-i-discover-what-is-up-with-my-electrical-bill

Comment: when you say the bill is huge, do you mean dollar wise, or usage wise?  Are both homes in the same city/town (supplied by same municipality)? Are both the homes using similar equipment (heating, cooling, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, the homes are in the same neighbourhood - approximately the same size with the same equipment.

Comment: If home1's meter almost stops spinning when you've got all your appliances shut off, you may consider if home2's electricity bills are going somewhere else. Check with your neighbors to see if they're subsidizing your home2 utility bills, by any chance.

Comment: And if your meter is busted, you'll certainly want to call your utility over to check. I would ask them to check both homes, just in case...

Answer (score 1):

By FAR the best bet for billing questions and complaints is to call your POCO (power company).
In my area they take high bill complaints very seriously and will send a representative out quickly.

Also, things like this are absolutely NOT grounding/earthing issues. It is possible that it is a neutral problem and the grounding has become part of the issue that way, but grounding has nothing to do with the day to day operation of the electrical system.